# Text removed when clicked in show/hide

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this example below, how do I make the "See more" text not disappear, at the moment the text is removed when clicked. I would like it to stay. Thanks a lot.

http://www.cssnewbie.com/example/showhide-content/

Comment: Please add your **relevant** code here.

Comment: provide the code which you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete all of the stuff in the `<script>` tag that references `shID+'-show'`.  That's the stuff that's showing/hiding the link.

For future reference:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showHide(shID) {
   if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
      if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
      }
      else {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
      }
   }
}
</script>

[...snip...]

<a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">See more.</a>
```

Removing the hide link stuff would give:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showHide(shID) {
   if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
      if (document.getElementById(shID).style.display != 'none') {
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
      }
      else {
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
      }
   }
}
</script>

[...snip...]

<a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">See more.</a>
```

*The above code is untested, but should work.*

Answer (score 1):

remove this line

```
onclick="showHide('example');return false;"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the below line to the code block under it.

Original:

```
<a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">See more.</a>
```

Modified:

```
<a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" >See more.</a>
```